# Spring Data ElasticSearch : parse full JSON test DSL query

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, parsing, dsl

In a java project, my input is a ElasticSearch DSL query written in full JSON text.
The goal of the java project is to execute this query using Spring Data ElasticSearch.
The problem is I did not find an easy way to parse the input JSON DSL query to a Spring Query object (interface `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query`)

For example, let us have this input query :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "default_field": "firstName",
                        "query": "toto"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "first_name": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "user.firstName"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I execute this query in a shell with curl command, here is a sample response :

```
[...]
{
  "_index": "demoindex02",
  "_id": "SBAlS4cBet7182k9ugY1",
  "_score": 0.01626052,
  "_source": {
    "_class": "com.elasticsearch.document.ElasticSearchDocument",
    "firstName": "toto"
  }
},
[...]
```

According to Spring Data ElasticSearch documentation,
I can easily parse the content of the "query" entry using the `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.StringQuery` object.
I just have to extract the JSON object string inside the "query" entry
and give it to the builder function.
For example : `StringQueryBuilder queryBuilder = StringQuery.builder("\"bool\":[...]\"query\":\"toto\"}}]}");`
In Spring Data Elasticsearch, the `@Query` annotation do the exact same thing.

However, I can not do the same for the "aggs" entry.
I did not find any object builder that works the same as the StringQuery builder :
parse an input JSON string DSL query and give you a `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.aggregations.Aggregate` object.
The `@Aggregation` (or similar) annotation does not seem to exist in Spring Data ElasticSearch.

So here are my first questions :

1. Does Spring Data Elastic provide such an aggregation parser ?
   If so, what is the related object ?
2. Is there an existing open source parser ? (in a open GitHug/GitLab/... project)
   If so, where can I find this project ? (I tried to google it but I did not found anything)

In the eventuality there is no such parser,
I tried to see how to make one of my own.
The `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.aggregations.Aggregate` object describes the "agg" entries in the `Kind` enumeration :

```
public enum Kind implements JsonEnum {
    AdjacencyMatrix("adjacency_matrix"),
    AutoDateHistogram("auto_date_histogram"),
    Avg("avg"),
[...]
```

The `AutoDateHistogram("auto_date_histogram")` details are described in the `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.aggregations.AutoDateHistogramAggregation` object.
I can see this entry use keywords such as : buckets,field,format ...
So in `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.aggregations` package, I can find all the information to parse the "agg" DSL entry.
But they are many complex objects and do not want to waste a lot of time by parsing each keyword/entry manually writing specific object parser for each.
So here is my last question :
Do you have any clue or tip to easily write such a parser ?

For information, I used those documentations :

- [Spring Data Elasticsearch - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods.at-query)
- [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html)
- [Search your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html)

I read official Spring and ElasticSearch documentation,
Read libraries code and used line-by-line debug
And also try to google the problem.

Unfortunatly, I did not found any answer.

I am expecting someone knows a existing project/library that can solve my problem,
or some clues to easily develop my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using `jakarta.json.stream.JsonParser` and `co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchRequest` as intermediaries

1. parse the raw JSON string request :

```
JsonParser jsonParser = Json.createParser(new StringReader("{\"query\":{...},\"aggs\":{...},...}"));
SearchRequest request = SearchRequest._DESERIALIZER.deserialize(jsonParser, jsonpMapper);
```

2. initialze Spring Data query : `NativeQueryBuilder nativeQueryBuilder = NativeQuery.builder();`
3. build the `NativeQueryBuilder` object using the `SearchRequest` object

```
nativeQueryBuilder.withQuery(request.query());
for (Entry<String, Aggregation> aggregationEntry : request.aggregations().entrySet()) {
    nativeQueryBuilder.withAggregation(aggregationEntry.getKey(),
                            aggregationEntry.getValue());
//...
}
```

Comment: is it possible to show the jsonpMapper code please?

Answer (score 0):

For my part, I have tried three approaches, including yours, but I never get the aggregation.

The basic query that works with Postman and returns the aggregated results:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "distinct_brand": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "brand",
                "size": 10000,
                "order": {
                "_key": "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test 1, with StringQuery:

```
Query query = new StringQuery("{" +
        "        \"match_all\" : {}" +
        "    }," +
        "    \"size\": 100," +
        "    \"aggs\": {" +
        "        \"distinct_brand\": {" +
        "            \"terms\": {" +
        "                \"field\": \"brand\"," +
        "                \"size\": 10000," +
        "                \"order\": {" +
        "                \"_key\": \"asc\"" +
        "        }" +
        "      }" +
        "    }" +
        "  }");

SearchHits<Brand> searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Brand.class);

    List<Brand> brandList = searchHits.getSearchHits().stream()
            .map(SearchHit::getContent)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Test 2, with AggregationBuilders and withAggregation:

```
Aggregation aggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms(ta -> ta.field("brand").size(10000));

Query query = NativeQuery.builder()
        .withQuery(q -> q.matchAll(ma -> ma))
        .withAggregation("distinct_brand", aggregation)
        .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10000))
        .build();

SearchHits<Brand> searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Brand.class);

List<Brand> brandList = searchHits.getSearchHits().stream()
        .map(SearchHit::getContent)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Test 3, with your example:

```
JsonpMapper jsonpMapper = new JacksonJsonpMapper();
JsonParser jsonParser = Json.createParser(new StringReader("{" +
        "        \"match_all\" : {}" +
        "    }," +
        "    \"size\": 100," +
        "    \"aggs\": {" +
        "        \"distinct_brand\": {" +
        "            \"terms\": {" +
        "                \"field\": \"brand\"," +
        "                \"size\": 10000," +
        "                \"order\": {" +
        "                \"_key\": \"asc\"" +
        "        }" +
        "      }" +
        "    }" +
        "  }"));

SearchRequest request = SearchRequest._DESERIALIZER.deserialize(jsonParser, jsonpMapper);

NativeQueryBuilder nativeQueryBuilder = NativeQuery.builder();

for (Map.Entry<String, Aggregation> aggregationEntry : request.aggregations().entrySet()) {
    nativeQueryBuilder.withAggregation(aggregationEntry.getKey(), aggregationEntry.getValue());
}

Query query = nativeQueryBuilder.withPageable(PageRequest.of(0, 10000)).build();

SearchHits<Brand> searchHits = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, Brand.class);

List<Brand> brandList = searchHits.getSearchHits().stream()
        .map(SearchHit::getContent)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Do you know why ?